# How to erase msp430f2619 flash using bsl?

Tags: uart, bootloader, msp430

I want to do mass erase on my msp430f2619 using bsl. I use software jump in my code to invoke bsl. I send 0x80, get 0x90 from BSL(ack). Then i send mass erase command and get 0x90 again. Then i power off my device, then i power on the device, then i send 0x80 and get 0x90, that means there was no mass erase operation.

Read command is not working too. I send password (0xFF 32 times), after that send rx command, then i get few coorect bytes, and then infinite raw of 0xff.

I think i miised something before jump to bsl, please give an example code, or step by step instruction on how to make software jump to bsl and make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending 0x80 only, then get back 0x90, this confirms you have entered into the BSL since this completes the required synchronization sequence (see section 2.1 of [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau319ae/slau319ae.pdf?ts=1634680205005&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)). You should not require the "RX password" command since the "Mass erase" command is not protected.

The next sequence after the synchronization is to send the desired command, which should be the "Mass erase". There is a format to each of the BSL commands called the data frame. You want to send the following data frame: eight mandatory bytes (note two dummy bytes), and two checksum bytes. Note the "Mass erase" command does not contain data bytes, but you need to calculate the checksum bytes. Here are the bytes to be sent to perform the mass erase:

```
80 18 04 04 dd dd 06 A5 CL CH
Where: dd = dummy bytes (any value accepted), CL = Checksum low, CH = Checksum high
```

After sending this data frame then you should receive the ACK (0x90) byte. Then power off the device.